# Power BI - Data refresh doesn't work for CSV File

Tags: csv, powerbi, dax

I am currently loading a local `csv` file. If I add a column/row `in the file`, I want to refresh the data in my power bi. If I press refresh in the Query Editor, nothing happens.
Do you have any ideas why that isn't working?

> EDIT

It works perfectly for MS Excel but doesn't work for CSV. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open the advanced editor, you will see that the original number of columns is defined. Delete that number and it should work!

Answer (score 0):

Try `Options -> Data Load -> Clear Cache` and afterwards refresh.